# Assigning value to members of list of list in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want this code to print Pascal triangle and I need to have the output of generate() to be `List<List<Integer>>` I have been struggling too much mostly because I am not comfortable with iterating over and assigning the values to list of list. Can you help me to figure the solution? I am not looking for fancy solution!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class PascalTriangle {

    public static long biCoeff(int n, int k) {
        if (n==k) {
            return (long) 1;
        }
        if (n==0) {
            return (long) n;
        }

        return (biCoeff(n-1, k-1)+biCoeff(n-1,k));
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> generate(int numRows) {
        List<List<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<numRows; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<l.get(i).size(); j++) {
                l.get(i).add((int) biCoeff(numRows, j));
            }

       }
       return l;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        generate(5);
    }
}
```

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at PascalTriangle.generate(PascalTriangle.java:25)
    at PascalTriangle.main(PascalTriangle.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code for generate method :

```
public static List<List<Integer>> generate(int numRows) {
        List<List<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            l.add(i, new ArrayList<Integer>());
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
                l.get(i).add((int) biCoeff(numRows, j));
            }
        }
        return l;
    }
```

Output :

> [[1], [1, 5], [1, 5, 10], [1, 5, 10, 10], [1, 5, 10, 10, 5]]

Other pattern you can have is (having 1 at end of each row):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Pascal {
    static List<List<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int noOfRows = 5;
        int counter = 0;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        generate(list, counter, noOfRows);
        System.out.println(l);
    }

    public static List<Integer> generate(List<Integer> list, int counter, int noOfRows) {
        l.add(list);
        List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        tempList.add(1);
        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
            tempList.add(list.get(i) + list.get(i - 1));
        }
        tempList.add(1);
        if (counter != noOfRows)
            generate(tempList, ++counter, noOfRows);
        return tempList;
    }
}
```

Output:

> [[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1], [1, 5, 10, 10,
>   5, 1]]

Comment: you know what's the trick to have 1 printed at the end of each one?

Comment: check updated answer. or please give me pattern that you want.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add a `List` to add items first.

```
public static List<List<Integer>> generate(int numRows) {
    List<List<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<numRows; i++){
        l.add(new List<Integer>()); // add this line
        //l.get(i).add((int) biCoeff(numRows, i));
        for (int j=0; j<l.get(i).size(); j++) {
            l.get(i).add((int) biCoeff(numRows, j));
        }

    }
    return l;
}
```

Actually this code won't compile since `List` is an interface and you cannot create its instance.
You will have to choose a class that implements `List` and use it instead of `new List<Integer>()`. For example, `new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>()`

Comment: it says : List is abstract it cannot be instantiated in the line you told to add

Comment: Choose one of implementations of `List` instead: for example: `new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>()`

Comment: initialize List  first.   new ArrayList<T>();